# How to clear fragment backstack till a specified fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter, fragment-backstack

I am working on an application that has tabs with viewpager. I am using fragmentstatepageradapter for handling the viewpager tabs. I am replacing the first fragment with nested fragments using the childFragmentmanager and adding the current fragment to the backstack. The control flow is as follows.

First tab fragment A -> Replaced with Fragment B -> Replaced with Fragment  C ->Replaced with Fragment  D.

Now when i click on a specific button in Fragment D, I need to go back to the fragment B, clearing the Fragments C,D from the backstack.

I tried

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(
    getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStac‌​kEntryAt(0).getId(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

But unsuccessfull. Can someone tell me the correct method to clear the backstack and navigate to fragment B from fragment D.?
This is my fragmentstatepageradapter

```
public class HomeViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are
    Context mcontext;                        // Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is
    int[] images;                        // created
    int NumbOfTabs;
    private Fragment mFragmentAtPos0;
    SparseArray<Fragment> registeredFragments = new SparseArray<Fragment>();
    Fragment homefragment;
    Context context;
    FragmentManager fragmentmanager;

    public HomeViewPagerAdapter(Context context, FragmentManager fm,
                                CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);
        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
        this.context = context;
        this.fragmentmanager = fm;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (position == 0) 
        {
            SharedPreferences LoginPref = this.context.getSharedPreferences("login_credentials", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            if (LoginPref.contains("login_pref") && LoginPref.getString("login_pref", "").equals("loggedin")) {
                homefragment = new SearchHomeFragment();
            } else {
                homefragment = new HomeScreenFragment();
            }
            return homefragment;
        } else if (position == 1) 
        {
            HomeCategoriesFragment homecategoriesfragment = new HomeCategoriesFragment();
            return homecategoriesfragment;

        } else if (position == 2) 
        {
            HomePriceComparisonFragment homepricecomparefragment = new HomePriceComparisonFragment();
            return homepricecomparefragment;
        } else if (position == 3) 
        {
            HomeEnterFeedFragment homeenterfeedfragment = new HomeEnterFeedFragment();
            return homeenterfeedfragment;
        } else {
            HomeMoreFragment homemorefragment = new HomeMoreFragment();
            return homemorefragment;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        Log.e("getItemPosition", "getItemPosition");
        if (object instanceof HomeScreenFragment)
            return POSITION_NONE;
        else
            return POSITION_UNCHANGED;

    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
        registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
          registeredFragments.remove(position);
        if(MyTabFragment.shouldDestroy) {
            super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
            MyTabFragment.shouldDestroy=false;
        }
    }

    public void resetScreendata() {
        if (homefragment != null) {
            homefragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
    public void resettoSearch() {

        if (homefragment != null) {
            homefragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack("search", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
        }
    }
    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position) {
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Titles[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }


}
```

And this is how i am replacing the fragment.

```
final SearchHomeFragment newFragment = new SearchHomeFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction =getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right,R.anim.slide_out_left,R.anim.slide_in_left,R.anim.slide_out_right);
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_mainLayout, newFragment);
transaction.addToBackStack("search");
transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you are adding fragments to backstack give them a name.

```
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentA");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentB");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentC");
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragmentD");
```

Then add this code on button click:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    FragmentManager fm = getActivity()
            .getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.popBackStack ("fragmentB", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Avijit Karmakar ,I tried to give name while adding to backstack and tried poping out from the backstack and didn't work. My viewpager and fragment tabs are inside another fragment for handling separate backstack for each tabs. And i am using homefragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack("search", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); to pop the last added 2 fragments. Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is popping *everything* off the stack of fragments.  Try using a specific name or id for fragment B instead of using the id for the the very first fragment in the stack.

Comment: I tried to give name while adding to backstack and tried poping out from the backstack and didn't work. My viewpager and fragment tabs are inside another fragment for handling separate backstack for each tabs. And i am using homefragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack("search", FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE); to pop the last added 2 fragments. Still not working.